# Daemon with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, daemon, launch-daemon

I am writing a script in python3 for Ubuntu that should be executed all X Minutes and should automatic start after logging in. Therefore I want to create a daemon (is it the right solution for that?) but I haven't found any modules / examples for python3, just for python 2.X. Do you know something what I can work with?

Thank you,

Comment: yes daemonizing your python script is good for that purpose. This [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675573/using-python-daemonizing-a-process/12844368#12844368) has great resource to look at, it will also work for python 3.

Comment: And if you just need it for ubuntu then goto System -> Prefrences -> Startup Application . Add you python command here.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the link looks very good :)

Comment: Welcome buddy, its the beauty of SO now it contains almost every thing that we need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for python script name is `monitor`. use following steps:

- copy monitor script in `/usr/local/bin/` (*not necessary*)
- Also add a copy in `/etc/init.d/`
- Then execute following command to make it executable

  `sudo -S chmod "a+x" "/etc/init.d/monitor"`
- At last run update.rc command

  `sudo -S update-rc.d "monitor"  "defaults" "98"`

this will execute you `monitor` whenever you login for all `tty`.

Comment: There is no point to have a copy both in /usr/local/bin and in /etc/init.d.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: But I don't know why I had to copy there also in my case!!...thats why I am suggesting him also.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Also There should not any problem if he copy in `bin` too .. Is it?

Comment: No, except that you now have two copies to keep updated. At the **minimum** make it a link. But there simply isn't any use of having it in `bin`, you don't need it.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: I agree with you, Thanks for your attention and idea Lennart.

Answer (score 5):

I would simply make the script, and have it somewhere, and then add a line to the crontab of the user who you want to run the script. This may be the root.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

To start the editor of the crontab

```
X * * * *    /usr/bin/python /path/to/the/script
```

This way the script will be executed every X minutes. No need to daemonize, no need to make your own timer in the script.